# Use ruby to go back to early lines and functions

Tags: ruby, loops, recursion

I am making a basic hangman game that will need to keep retracing until the game is over.  I'm trying to figure out the correct ruby way to go back to these lines. Here is a rough pseudocode example:

```
some_function

end

another_function

end 
if x > 5 go back to some_function
if x < 5 go back to another_function
```

Comment: Are you trying to use Ruby as if it was assembly code?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: my question is how to execute a piece of code that would create a loop that goes back to these functions

Comment: It's not being used as if it's assembly code, it's being used as if it has a `goto`-type statement. Many languages have that, not just assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions are how you run some code somewhere else and return back to where you started.  Loops are how you run the same code again and again until some condition is met.

Here is some incomplete code to demonstrate.

```
def some_function(x)
    puts "x is #{x} some function"
end

def another_function(x)
    puts "x is #{x} in another function"
end

def something_else(x)
    puts "x is #{x} in something else"
end

# I've left are_we_done undefined, it's the condition for
# stopping the loop.  I've also left get_x undefined.
while !are_we_done
    x = get_x

    if x > 5
        some_function(x)
    elsif x < 5
        another_function(x)
    else # x is 5
        something_else(x)
end
```

Teaching these fundamentals is beyond a Stack Overflow answer. I would suggest going through a tutorial like [Learn Ruby The Hard Way](http://learnrubythehardway.org/book/) to learn the fundamentals of loops and functions.